# Windows Phone open url in desktop version

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm using this code to open url in my app

```
            var task = new WebBrowserTask();
            task.Uri = new Uri(Link, UriKind.Absolute);
            task.Show();
```

now I have requirement to open this page in desktop version. How can I do that?

In iOS I set user agent, but there's no such param for browsertask on WP.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible by any means. System settings (in this case Internet Explorer settings) cannot be changed by your application.

If you are the owner of the website, you can specify some special query parameter that will force desktop mode. If this is a general purpose app, you might as well forget about it.

Comment: No other solutions on WP?

Comment: Solutions to what? You can open a web page with the current system settings, they are unchangeable from your (or for that matter any other) app.

Answer (score 0):

This can do it !

```
public void MyBrowser()
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.stackoverflow.com"), null, "User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; XBLWP7; ZuneWP7)");
    }
```